# How to fix "Session was invalidated" Exception?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I have an endpoint (/logout) that invalidate the session manually by calling HttpSession#invalidate(). Sometimes i got the following exception (Within 1000 request it happens about a dozen times):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session was invalidated
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionRepository.save(RedisSessionRepository.java:129)
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionRepository.save(RedisSessionRepository.java:45)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:229)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:145)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
        2 lines skipped for [org.apache.catalina]
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        2 lines skipped for [org.apache.catalina]
```

It looks like that the session is tried to be saved after it was invalidated. Is there way to prevent a save after the session was invalidated or is there a way to make sure the invalidate state is written after the save?

I found a similar case here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/9128#issuecomment-984972101 but there it is related to spring security.

I looks to me that there is a current session object at SessionRepositoryFilter#commitSession() although it should have been removed from the current request.

Spring boot 3.2.3 (without spring security), Redisson and RedisIndexedSessionRepository with flushmode:on_save and savemode:on_set_attribute is used. The service is behind spring cloud gateway